# Fourier Transform of exponential

Tags: fourier-transform, transform, fourier

While solving Example 4.1 of Signals and Systems by Alan Oppenheim. Example 4.1 is:
$$ x(t)=e^{-at}u(t), a>0$$
and the transform I get is:
$$ X(j\omega)\frac{1}{a+j\omega}, a>0$$

The problem is understanding the sketch: 
The sketch is drawn for both the values $+a$ and $-a$> i dont understand why it $-a$ when $a>0$ is defined.
[image]

Comment: $a>0$, no question about it. It is the frequency variable $\omega$ which can take on negative values, e.g. $\omega=-a$ (which is of course negative if $a$ is positive).

Comment: "The sketch is drawn for both the values $+a $ and $−a$.  i dont understand why it $-a$ when $a>0$ is defined."  The _variable_ on the horizontal axis is $\omega$, the radian frequency which can take on all real number values. The $a$ and $-a$ are **labels** on the axes. Surely we can agree that if $a =1$, say, then there should be a point on the horizontal axis that bears the label $1$ and another with label $-1$? Ditto for labels $2a=2$ and $-2a=-2$ etc? The reason for not putting in these additional labels is that $a$ and $-a$ are of particular importance as the 3dB down points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot is of $$\mid X\left(i\omega\right) \mid = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{a+j\omega}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a-j\omega}\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + \omega^2}}$$

against $\omega$

In particular $\omega$ can be equal to $-a$.

This checks out with [**Wolfram alpha**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%284%2Bx%5E2%29%29%5E-1)

Comment: can you please check this [question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27179/confusion-in-basics-of-laplace-transform/27181?noredirect=1#comment50853_27181)